# CodeBuild is still passing the Test stage

Tags: python, devops, aws-codebuild

I am having an issue when deploying my application in that my tests are not running. Its a simple script but still code build is bypassing my test.
I have specified unittest and placed the path to my unittest-buildspec in the console
my app looks like:

-Chalice

--.chalice

-- BuildSpec

---- build.sh

---- unittest-buildspec.ym

-- Tests

---- test_app.py

---- test-database.py

-- app.py

```
version: 0.2

phases:
install:
runtime-versions:
  python: 3.7
commands:
  - pip install -r requirements_test.txt

build:
  commands:
    - echo Build started on `date` ---
    - pip install -r requirements_test.txt
    - ./build.sh
    - pytest --pep8 --flakes  

artifacts:
  files: 
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: 'my-build*'
  discard-paths: yes
```

My build.sh is in the same folder as well

```
#!/bin/bash
pip install --upgrade awscli
aws --version
cd ..
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv /tmp/venv
. /tmp/venv/bin/activate
export PYTHONPATH=.
py.test tests/ || exit 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues in the buildspec you shared:

1. 'install' and 'build' phases' indentation is incorrect. They should come under 'phases'.
2. Set '+x' on the build.sh before running it.

#### Fixed buildspec.yml:

```
version: 0.2 

phases: 
    install: 
        runtime-versions: 
          python: 3.7 
        commands: 
            - pip install -r requirements_test.txt 

    build: 
        commands: 
            - echo Build started on `date` --- 
            - pip install -r requirements_test.txt 
            - chmod +x ./build.sh 
            - ./build.sh 
            - pytest --pep8 --flakes   

artifacts: 
    files:  
        - '**/*' 
    base-directory: 'my-build*' 
    discard-paths: yes
```

Also please note that your 'build.sh' uses "/bin/bash" interpreter, while the script will work, the shell is not technically "bash", so any bash specific functionality will not work. The CodeBuild's shell is mysterious, it will run the usual scripts, it is just not bash.